# Factorize the natural number $n$ with the method $\rho$-rho of Pollard

Tags: number-theory, factoring, cryptography, natural-numbers

I want to factorize the natural number $n=32437$ with the method $\rho$-rho of Pollard.

$$$$

I have done the following:

Let's consider $x=y=2$ ($x_1=y_1=2$) and $c=1$. We have then $f(x)=x^2+c=x^2+1$.

Then:

\begin{equation*}\begin{matrix}x_{i+1}=f(x_i)\bmod n & y_{i+1}=f(f(y_i))\bmod n & c & d=gcd (|x_{i+1}-y_{i+1}|, n) \\  5 & 26 & 1 & 1 \\ 26 & 4212 & 1 & 1 
 \\ 677 & 5842 & 1 & 1 \\ 4212 & 26380 & 1 & 163 \neq 1, n \end{matrix}\end{equation*}

Since the last gcd is neither equal to $1$ nor equal to $n$, this number is a factor of $n$. The other factor is $\frac{n}{163}=199$.

$$$$

Is everything correct? Have I applied correctly the method? t the end can I just say that the other facto is $\frac{n}{163}$ ?

Comment: You can say *an* other factor is $n/163$. If all you want is *some* factorization, that'll do. If you want the complete factorization into primes, you still have to decide whether you can factor $163$ and $199$ any further.

Comment: Exactly how Pollard-Rho works, in this case the factorization is finished because both $163$ and $199$ are prime, showing this primality however is not part of the Pollard-Rho method, the purpose of this method is just to find a nontrivial factor. But Gerry is right that we must show this if the exercise is "factorize N". If $a\mid N$ is a nontrivial factor, clearly $b=\frac{N}{a}$ is the nontrivial so-called "cofactor".

Comment: In short : Everything correct !

Comment: Great!! Thanks a lot!! :-)